# choosing a random word from an array of words

Tags: javascript

I'm working on the following program. My task is to set the program to choose a random word so then the user can guess it I added the following math.random() method but it does not work here is the code:

```
var words_to_be_guessed = ["VIENNA", "HELSINKI", "COPENHAGEN",
                           "LONDON", "BERLIN", "AMSTERDAM"] ;

// here is what I added
var words_to_be_guessedd = words_to_be_guessed[Math.floor(Math.random()*words_to_be_guessed.lenght)];

var guessed_characters = [ '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-',
                           '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-',
                           '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-' ] ;

guessed_characters = guessed_characters.slice(0, word_to_be_guessed.length);

function string_array_to_string(given_array_of_strings){
   var string_to_return = "";
   for (string_index in given_array_of_strings){
      string_to_return = string_to_return + given_array_of_strings[string_index];
   }
   return string_to_return;
}
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: What is not working?  What error message do you get?

Comment: Please take a look at the errors you should be getting. There are some typo's in your code that should be simple to debug.

Comment: I fixed the typo's but still the page that I get im my browser shows the following I put a screen shot above

Comment: Btw, your alphabet is missing letter U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the typo in `length`, there's a typo in this line:

```
guessed_characters = guessed_characters.slice(0, word_to_be_guessed.length);
```

Should be:

```
guessed_characters = guessed_characters.slice(0, words_to_be_guessed.length);
                                                     ^
```

Also, a simpler way to build a array of dashes of the desired length would be this:

```
Array(5).join('-').split('');
```

(Where `5` is the desired length, in your case, `word_to_be_guessed.length`)
Exlanation:

```
Array(5)      // Create an array with 5 `undefined` elements. Result: [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];
  .join('-')  // Join these empty elements with a dash.       Result: "-----";
  .split(''); // Split this string at every character.        Result: ["-", "-", "-", "-;"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelt `length` as `lenght`:

```
var words_to_be_guessedd = words_to_be_guessed[
    Math.floor(Math.random()*words_to_be_guessed.length)];
```

This should work.